# Python construct a mutable global object from another global object

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, global-variables, openid-connect, flask-oidc

I have `main.py` and `app.py`. `app.py` contains `create_app()` which returns the `app` object. `main.py` calls `create_app()`. I have to construct a mutable global object in `main.py`. This global object takes `app` as input parameter. This seems complex to me in python. How do I possibly achieve this global object construction when the application starts up?

Specifically, I am using `flask_oidc` and needs to construct an `oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)` in `main.py` and makes `oidc` object available in other controller .py files. This `oidc` object will store user info and validates if a user is authenticated.

Any advice and insight is appreciated.

Comment: You can create a singleton class that has the `oidc` attribute, and use it across the application

Comment: Or you can simple create a global object `oidc` in a module and import that variable in the files you want

Comment: How does the second option work since it required python `app` as input parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a module that initialize your `oidc` object at the start of the application

`helper.py`

```
oidc = None # global instance

def init_oidc(app):
  # initalise the oidc here and assign to the global variable
  global oidc
  oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)
  return oidc
```

`main.py`

```
import init_oidc from helper


app = create_app()
# init only once at the start of the application
oidc = init_oidc(app)
```

In other controller files
`sample_controller.py`

```
import oidc from helper

# use the same oidc here
```

The other option is to create a singleton class with a attribute oidc in it, it will be helpfull if you need other methods along with oidc

Comment: `oidc = OpenIDConnect(app)` -> `oidc = OpenIDConnect(*args)` ?

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately the log shows `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user_getinfo'` when the application runs. Not sure if the object was constructed properly at all. I access `oidc` in another file with `from src.common.Authentication import oidc`

Comment: Are you sure the call to the function that constructs the `oidc` object is before any use?
Also, make sure both uses the  same process the one that constructs the object and the one that uses it

Comment: I only call the `init_oidc` from main.py, the entry point of the application. In the consumer .py, I import the global `oidc` object directly.

Comment: can you share the code, in the question.?

Comment: Using `impot oidc from helper` within the consumer function works. Putting it outside doesn't. It is always NoneType. This is a problem when I need to use the `oidc` object in a decorator. For example: `@app.route('/api')
@oidc.accept_token()`

Comment: This is solved by following to https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/